# Class-D amplifier output rings when connected to LC filter

Tags: transformer, h-bridge, full-bridge, class-d

I made a class-D amplifier with an output transformer, as you can see in the simplified schematic. Gate resistors are actually 10 Ω, not 2.2 Ω.

[image]

[image]

The supply is 24 V, the PWM signal has a frequency of 500 kHz, and the modulated signal is 100 kHz.

The circuit itself works, with minimal ringing at switching nodes and it is acceptable. The transformer is handwound with a ferrite N87 toroid (35.5 mm) and currently has 8 turns at the primary and 16 turns at the secondary.

I tried it with a resistive load of 200 Ω directly connected to the secondary side of the transformer, and it is OK; just a low-pass effect due to inductance and load.

But when I connected the LC filter shown in SPICE, the secondary side starts to ring at some MHz, while the switching nodes are perfect with smooth waveforms.

I tried also with only a second-order filter and it is the same.

Any ideas?

[image]
Output without filter on 200 Ω load

[image]
Switching node 1 during oscillations on secondary side

[image]
Switching node 2 during oscillations on secondary side

[image]
Oscillations on secondary side

Comment: Try adding some series resistance with the inductors.

Comment: Use "Real Inductors" for your simulation. They series resistance will dampend the oscillation. If not enough, try and add some series resistance.

Comment: The oscillation in in the real pcb, not in the simulation. And starts only when the filter Is connected.

Comment: @mtx4 What is the leakage inductance of the real transformer. You also need to know the other parasitics of the magnetics, such as the resistances and capacitances. You can use the models that Coilcraft has for their inductors and see if that gives you a better simulation. Also, what sort of dead time is used in the H-bridge?

Comment: I don't know what Is the leakage inductance.   Yes I can try a more real model, but the real circuit usually Is different from simulation. Dead time Is 10 ns.

Comment: Between the positive of V7 and ground, a nice capacitor would be needed to send all the harmonics to ground and the oscillations will most likely disappear.

Comment: You may wish to _edit your question_ with a schematic that's expanded out to include the gate drive details.  While you're editing your question, state whether it oscillates.

Comment: Please show a winding diagram for your transformer.  There are many meanings of "oscillation"; please show waveforms to illustrate what kind is meant here.

Comment: I added a simple schematic and info about transformer. Oscillations are only on the secondary side, there is a sinewave of few MHz and not the 100 kHz signal I expected.

Comment: What’s your feedback situation?

Comment: I'm seeing severe ringing, but not sustained oscillations -- is that ringing what you're calling "oscillation?"  Note that the answers suggesting some sort of Q-killer still apply.

Comment: If you don't see ringing in your Spice simulation you may want to give it a realistic coupling coefficient in the transformer.  Even toroids don't have a coupling coefficient of 1.  If it makes the simulation match reality better -- edit your question.

Comment: Can you please show the secondary side ringing as well? I don't see a winding diagram for the toroid (and, surely all the wires are not 14AWG?). Perhaps you can show a photograph of it?

Comment: I added a picture with secondary side oscillation. This particular situations occurs only with output capacitors installed, with no inductors, so without a proper LC filter. Even some capacitors alone make this things oscillates.

Comment: So the output circuit shown, isn't even what you were testing? There is good reason why we ask for the *circuit being tested*!

Comment: The output waveform refers to that circuit with L4 and L3 replaced by a short circuit. With the inductors installed I have the same waveform, with different amplitide. So that is the real output of the tested circuit.

Comment: I've edited the question since there is absolutely no oscillation anywhere in the circuit. There is ringing, since you've added a non-dissipative tank as the load.

Answer (score 4):

Q: How do I build an oscillator?

A: Try to build an amplifier.

Q: How do I build a noise generator?

A: Try to build an oscillator.

I can't answer your question, but here's an approach to see how susceptible your circuit, as designed, is to oscillation.

In your simulation, replace L1 with a current generator.  Set its DC value to some reasonable amount for your real circuit; put it somewhere in range of the RMS to the peak current you expect in L1.  Set it's AC magnitude to something convenient, like 1A (SPICE's AC sweep assumes a linear circuit, so the actual number doesn't matter).

Sweep the frequency from a decade below the oscillation frequency you're observing to a decade above.  Plot the AC voltage across the current source.
By default you'll get a Bode plot.  Since \$E = I Z\$, the AC voltage divided by the AC current that you set will be the complex impedance of the circuit.

If, at any point, the phase shift of the voltage exceeds \$\pm 90^\circ\$, then the real part of the impedance is negative, and you have a circuit that, with the right load, will oscillate.

You can go three ways from there:

1. Find the worst-case negative real impedance, and just bung in a resistor in series with L1.  Make the resistor at least twice the value of your worst-case negative real impedance to make sure its well and truly swamped out.  That should give you a phase margin between \$45^\circ\$ and \$60^\circ\$ (I should know this, you *can* know this if you do the math).
2. Experiment with your gate drive, or source degeneration on your upper FETs, to kill the negative real resistance.  I don't have much experience with this so I can't help much -- I just know that emitter/cathode/source followers can be unstable with inductive loads, so I suspect that's your problem here.
3. *Separate from the power circuit*, set up your load on L1, then drive L1 with an independent AC current source, and look at *it's* voltage to get the driving stage's load impedance.  If you sum the drive and the load impedance together and get a point that has a purely negative (i.e., no imaginary part) impedance, then that's your predicted oscillation frequency.  You can use that to guide how much of a ballast resistor to put in series with L1 -- if you trust your simulation.

Comment: A series resistor to reduce the Q-factor of the LC filter is hardly ever a good solution in the case of Class D amps, as these are usually relatively high powered amps, and series resistor would decrease efficiency massively.. A better way is a parallel resistor to damp the Q. Practically, one also strings a C in series with this resistor and calls it snubber.

Comment: Good point, and one I should have thought of myself.  The general process of using simulation to get into the ballpark still holds, I think.

Comment: Re. your first part: Everything oscillates at the first prototype, except an oscillator.

Answer (score 1):

LC filters usually have a rather high Q. This means that when you pass a wide range of frequencies into them (e.g. a PWM waveform), they will strongly amplify specific frequencies.

Preventing this **requires** one of the following two counter-measures:

1. damping the LC filters with a snubber
2. feedback-regulation of the output with proper frequency compensation

In most buck designs, the 2nd option is implicitly implemented, because they are used as voltage regulators, so they must have output voltage feedback.

However, in your case you are designing it as an open-loop driver. If your bandwidth is low, you could still implement feedback, but if you have large bandwidth requirements that make feedback unfeasible, then your only good option is a snubber.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxA9fg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The component values are examples. But all LC filters will have peaking, unless there is some unusually high ESR involved. Below is the filter response without and then with the snubbers:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but actually the circuiti oscillates with parallel capacitors on the output, without the inductors. So the leakage inductance of the transformer and about 50 nF are enough to make an LC filter that oscillates. I'll try a snubber anyway.

Comment: @mxt4 Yeah, the leakage and load capacitor are obviously a high enough Q to make it ring. To get a useful damping, try with a snubber C that is at least ~5x your filter C and then strap some resistance in series. Or simulate first to find the leakage inductance (match with ringing frequency, and then tune R and C until your satisfied. On the plus side: the leakage inductance gives your free filtering without another inductor (once you snub the resonance).

Comment: I made a new simple LC filter, with math calculations, critically damped with Q=0,707, so no peaking at all in the frequency response. L = 270 uH and C = 10 nF Well, the secondary side rings again, so problem not solved.

Comment: @mxt4 Ok how did you damp it ? Did you place an actual 100 load resistor? Or are you relying on some Coax cables as load?

Comment: The filter should be naturally damped with that LC values. So I didn't add a snubber. The load is 200 ohm resistor connected to the output of amplifier by a BNC cable.

Comment: @mxt4 Agreed.. One last thought (just to go sure): try to hook up the 200 ohm directly in parallel to the filter C as far as possible, i.e. no BNC cable.